# Show that recursion

Tags: numerical-methods

Hi I have the following problem:

> Let $$c_{v,\mu}=\int_a^bw_v(t)(b-t)^{\mu}dt\:\:\:\:\:\:\:,w_v(t)=\prod_{l=0}^{v-1}(t-t_{j-l})$$
>   with $v=0,...$ and $\mu=0,...$
>
> Show that $$c_{v+1,\mu}=(b-t_{j-v})c_{v,\mu}-c_{v,\mu+1}$$

I already tried to calculate the integral, but I would have to use the integration by parts far too often. I think there is an easier solution to that problem. Can someone help me here please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $w_v(t)=\prod_{t=0}^{v-1}(t-t_{j-l})$ what are $j$ and $l$ ... and $t_{?}$ ?

Comment: these are in this case variables with no specific value.

Comment: Do you mean $$w_v(t)=\prod_{\color{red}{l}=0}^{v-1}(t-t_{j-l})$$?

Comment: thanks, already edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that 
$$ c_{\nu+1,\mu} = \int_a^b (t-t_{j-\nu})\; w_\nu(t)\;(b-t)^\mu \;\mathrm{d}t$$
and 
$$ c_{\nu,\mu+1} = \int_a^b (b-t)\; w_\nu(t)\;(b-t)^\mu \;\mathrm{d}t$$
Adding above equations,
$$ c_{\nu+1,\mu} + c_{\nu,\mu+1} = \int_a^b (b-t_{j-\nu})\; w_\nu(t)\;(b-t)^\mu \;\mathrm{d}t  = (b-t_{j-\nu}) \;c_{\mu,\nu}$$